# Setting php generated html table in parts side by side

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I made this code to extract data from mysql and bring the results on the page. The results that the code generated goes down the page. I would like them to be set side by side, may be 30 rows, then the next 30 rows. (After 3 columns of table,if there are still more data, they go on like this down the page if possible). I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865169/set-tables-as-side-by-side-instead-of-straight-down-while-doing-a-while-loop?rq=1) about this, but since I am new to this,I couldn't apply the offered solution there to my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

A simple illustration to show the solution I need:

[image]

```
<table class="result-table">
 <tr>
  <th>Week</th> 
  <th>Ball1</th> 
  <th>Ball2</th>
  <th>Ball3</th>
  <th>Ball4</th>
  <th>Ball5</th>
  <th>Ball6</th>
 </tr>


 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT Week, Ball1, Ball2, Ball3, Ball4, Ball5, Ball6 FROM sample";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Week"]."</td><td>" . $row["Ball1"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["Ball2"]. "</td><td>". $row["Ball3"]. "</td><td>". $row["Ball4"].  "</td><td>".$row["Ball5"]. "</td><td>". $row["Ball6"]. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>     


</table>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "side by side." You have only one table. Do you want TWO tables, each with columns for Week and Ball1 through Ball6? Or are you trying to page, so that you get 30 rows on one screen, and then you click a Next button for the next 30 rows?

Comment: Yes, there is one table generated which goes down the page. Instead of this, or pagination, I seek a solution to set the table in 3 pieces side bye side. After the first 30 rows, then it continues with another 30 rows  on the right side of the first 30 row, and then the third 30 rows. it goes on like this. I also inserted an image to show it now.

Comment: The image is too small to be readable.

Comment: Add an order by clause to your SQL statement so the week numbers are in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want separate tables for each 30 values displayed side-by-side, but with your image it appears that they would also go on to a separate row after three groups of 30.  That part can be handled with CSS (i.e. `width: 33%;`), so I will provide a solution that handles the PHP portion.  The following uses a counter to separate each of group of 30 into a new table.

```
<table class="result-table">
 <tr>
  <th>Week</th> 
  <th>Ball1</th> 
  <th>Ball2</th>
  <th>Ball3</th>
  <th>Ball4</th>
  <th>Ball5</th>
  <th>Ball6</th>
 </tr>


 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT Week, Ball1, Ball2, Ball3, Ball4, Ball5, Ball6 FROM sample";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // HERE IS WHERE I ADD A COUNTER
  $counter = 1;
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Week"]."</td><td>" . $row["Ball1"] . "</td><td>"
            . $row["Ball2"]. "</td><td>". $row["Ball3"]. "</td><td>". $row["Ball4"].  "</td><td>".$row["Ball5"]. "</td><td>". $row["Ball6"]. "</td></tr>";


            // HERE I INCREMENT THE COUNTER, AND REPEAT THE END OF THE CURRENT TABLE/BEGINNING OF THE NEXT IF $counter%30 == 0
            $counter++;
            if($counter % 30 == 0) { ?>
                </table>
                <table class="result-table">
                     <tr>
                      <th>Week</th> 
                      <th>Ball1</th> 
                      <th>Ball2</th>
                      <th>Ball3</th>
                      <th>Ball4</th>
                      <th>Ball5</th>
                      <th>Ball6</th>
                     </tr>
            <?php }
    }
echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>     


</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, mtr.web. I tried your solution, it solves the problem. and I can adjust it with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Do get the output you describe, you can fetch all rows at once into an associative array, then step through the columns in groups based on the number of columns to display.

**NOTE:** I added an order by clause to your SQL statement.

```
<?php
    $numRowsPerGroup = 30;
    $rowTitles = array(
        array('title' => "Ball1",'colname' => "Ball1"), 
        array('title' => "Ball2",'colname' => "Ball2"),
        array('title' => "Ball3",'colname' => "Ball3"),
        array('title' => "Ball4",'colname' => "Ball4"),
        array('title' => "Ball5",'colname' => "Ball5"),
        array('title' => "Ball6",'colname' => "Ball6")
    );
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT Week, Ball1, Ball2, Ball3, Ball4, Ball5, Ball6 FROM sample ORDER BY week";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    $allrows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if($allrows) {
        $rownum = 0;
        while($rownum < $numrows) {
            //  Output heading row for this group
            echo "<table>\n";
            echo "<thead>\n";
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "  <th>&nbsp;</th>\n";
            //  Calculate the starting and ending column numbers. These correspond to the rows in the results
            $startColNo = $rownum;
            $endColNo = $rownum + $numRowsPerGroup;
            if($endColNo > $numrows) {
                $endColNo = $numrows;
            }
            //  Output the week column headers
            for($colNo = $startColNo;$colNo < $endColNo;$colNo++) {
                echo "  <th>".$allrows[$colNo]['week']."</th>\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
            echo "</thead>\n";
            echo "<tbody>\n";
            //  Output each item type row of the columns for this group.
            foreach($rowTitles as $idx => $rowInfo) {
                echo "<tr>\n";
                //  Step through the columns for this group for this item within the range.
                echo "  <td class='rowtitle'>".$rowInfo['title']."</td>\n";
                for($colNo = $startColNo;$colNo < $endColNo;$colNo++) {
                    echo "  <td>".$allrows[$colNo][$rowInfo['colname']]."</td>\n";
                }
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</tbody>\n";
            echo "</table>\n";
            $rownum = $endColNo + 1;
        }
    } else { 
        echo "<p>0 results</p>\n"; 
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and solution, Sloan. Unfortunately, I got some errors, and I don't think I can figure it out by myself now. Notice: Use of undefined constant numRowsPerGroup - assumed 'numRowsPerGroup' on line 58 which is             $endColNo = $rownum + numRowsPerGroup; but I will check your code again later, I'llneed a little time.

Comment: That's a missing $ sign. I've edit the code above. I had added a comment I do not see now that is won't output as your updated question specifies. I added before I saw your update.